# No text login screen after update to Debian 11

Tags: debian, systemd, grub2

After upgrading my Debian 10 server to Debian 11, an issue occurred: after the boot process is complete, the login screen is not shown and I cannot login on the server using the plugged keyboard.

The screen keep showing ghosts of the systemd boot logs, but the first line is erased and became black. Then nothing appends anymore: I can press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` or any other keys combinations to try switching to other terminals, press `Enter`, etc. the screen will never be updated. The only keystroke that does something is `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Suppr` witch reboot the system.

Moreover, I can normally login to the server using SSH and all other services seems perfectly functional.

I didn't installed any specific graphic drivers as I'm only using this server in text mode. The VGA controller is an **old Nvidia** ship *NVIDIA Corporation C79 [ION] [10de:087d] (rev b1)*.

I've updated my system to **Debian 12** to see if it fixes the issue but nothing changed.

Currently the **linux kernel is 6.1.0-10-amd64** but I kept the old 4.19.0-24-amd64 kernel installed and, if I boot on it, the login screen works normally.

I don't know where to check anymore. Any advices on debugging this issue will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: perhaps check the output of `dmesg`

Comment: try boot with `nomodeset` parameter appending to kernel kernel in grub

Comment: Amazing: adding `nomodeset` fixed the issue. Thanks! Feel free to post that as an answer so I can accept it.